SQL QUERY with custom columns from SUM
I would like to build a SQL query to get the sum of hours(difference between end and start) by week for each person.
In my main table, I have 3 columns  :



ID
startDT
endDT




1
01/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 12:00


1
01/01/2024 14:00
01/01/2024 17:30


2
09/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 12:00


2
10/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 11:00


2
11/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 10:00


3
01/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 10:00


3
08/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 12:00


3
15/01/2024 08:00
01/01/2024 11:00



The result I expect :



ID
W01
W02
W03




1
7.5
0
0


2
0
9
0


3
2
4
3



Thanks for your help

Ok, what is your question? What exactly doesn't work as you expect? Anyway, you should provide some sample input data.

I don't know how to get custom columns with calculated result from my main table

Having the weeks as columns makes your problem much harder and the solution inflexible - if you add more data that gives you W04, for example, you’d probably have to edit your SQL - so could you do this as rows instead? In any case, what’s your definition of WK01? Week 1 compared to the earliest date in your table, compared to a fixed date (what date?) or something else?

Define week. (ISO 8601's Monday - Sunday, or something else.)

I get the week number with DATEPART(week,startDT) function

which sql are you using ?

There are some issues with you sample data and result data. The biggest one being, endDT can be before startDT and each row is spanning over multiple weeks. ID 2 for example would not be 9 for week 2.

Code done in SQL Server, consists of 3 steps

Create a CTE query to calculate the time difference and the week number
Create a CTE query to sum hours by ID and week number
Create a PIVOT Table to Convert Weeks to Columns
Note: Date corrected data were used to fit the example

Solution
WITH hours_calculated as (
    SELECT [ID]
      ,[startDT]
      ,[endDT]
      , DATEDIFF(hh, [startDT], [endDT]) as Hours_Difference
      , CAST((DAY([startDT])-1)/7   AS INT) +1 AS WeekNumber
    FROM [development].[dbo].[hours_by_week]
), weeks_calculated as (

select ID, WeekNumber,SUM(Hours_Difference) as total_hours from hours_calculated group by ID, WeekNumber

)
select ID , [1] as W01,[2] as W02,[3] as W03,[4] as W04,[5] as W05
from weeks_calculated AS SourceTable
pivot
(
    SUM(total_hours)
    FOR WeekNumber IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5] )
)  AS PivotTable;

Output
ID  W01   W02   W03     W04     W05
1   7     NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL
2   NULL     9  NULL    NULL    NULL
3   2        4  3       NULL    NULL

Schema
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hours_by_week](
    [ID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [startDT] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [endDT] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

References
Group by week of a particular month in sql server
How to get total number of hours between two dates in sql server?
